# URL Redirection for localhost With IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, url-rewriting, iis-express

**Environment :** Development

**Technologies Used :** ASp.Net MVC 3, ASp.Net Web Forms, IIS Express, VS 2010 SP1.

**Scenario :**

We have implemented separate website module as actual separate .Net solutions. eg.

- For User Account related features, site runs at localhost:7080/.
- For search, site runs at localhost:7020/
- And a project holding common UI element runs at localhost:7090.
- While our main site using all these separate modules runs at localhost:8000. This is the only application which is in ASp.Net webforms (it's legacy code.)

This setting allow us to deploy only required module(s) in production.

In production, these sites has urls like,

www.example.com/account

www.example.com/search

www.example.com/common

Each of these project is actually a separate website in IIS and a redirect engine redirects the URL to appropriate website.

**Problem :**

All is good and fine in production, the challenge is only in development environment. We cannot use full IIS due to restrictions from system admin teams (humph) and have to use IIS Express.

What we want is to achieve this,

[http://]localhost:8000/useraccount redirects to [http://]localhost:7020

[http://]localhost:8000/search redirects to [http://]localhost:7080

etc. In short we want to mimic our production environment.

So is there any suggestion about what kind of URL redirection I can use to achieve this ? I did a fair bit of research but couldn't figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do it exactly the same as production? IIS Express supports the url rewrite module which I assume is how you do it with the full version of IIS. Install webmatrix which includes the rewrite module by default and you can use the webmatrix gui to configure IIS express and your rewrite conditions.